# Url rewritting multiple domains and subfolders asp.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have got some site on on **http://mydomain.com/mysite**, with few dynamic subsites http://mydomain.com/mysite/category1, http://mydomain.com/mysite/othercategory2

I would like to access mysite/{dynamiccategoryname} from other address **http://otherdomain.com**. It should work with mysite and mysite/category1 ...

```
http://otherdomain.com should show http://mydomain.com/mysite 
http://otherdomain.com/category1 should show http://mydomain.com/mysite/category1
```

**but not with redirecting client**.

Comment: This can be done using only IIS redirection settings.

Comment: But sites are hosted in one aaplication pool and site (multiple hostnames: mydomain.com and otherdomain.com)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with URL rewriting. You basically need to rewrite all requests with hostname otherdomain.com to /mysite/*. This can be done with the following rewrite rule:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite all request for otherdomain.com to /mysite">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^otherdomain\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/mysite/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Another solution is to set up a secondary site in IIS, with hostname otherdomain.com on the same IP but let the path of that site point to the physical path of the /mysite folder. But if you need the ASP.NET MVC application of mydomain.com on otherdomain.com as well that will not work of course. But it can be a solution if otherdomain.com is e.g. just for serving static content (images, css, script).